# Is there a way to avoid a Firestore field from reaching a negative value?

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app where a Firestore field value decreases by 45 every time a specific button is pressed.
I achieved this by using Firestore's `FieldValue.increment()` as shown below:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get().then((_) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).update({
        "example": FieldValue.increment(-45),
    });
});
```

The problem is that I can't let the field `example` reach less than zero.
I tried using the `.where()` method, but it doesn't apply for specific documents, in this case, the current user document.

```
Future<void> example() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('example', isLessThan: 45)
        .get()
        .then(((value) {
      print('subtracting results in a negative value');
    }));
  }
```

As it is clearly stated in the documentation, *"only documents satisfying provided condition are included in the result set"*, it is evident that document-specific queries cannot be made, therefore my problem cannot be solved this way.

Ideally, an `if` condition where a field reference meets the condition (`< 45`) would solve the problem, but as far as I'm concerned, Firestore doesn't currently support a FieldReference, as opposed to `CollectionReference` and `DocumentReference`.

I'm relatively new to Flutter and I've been working with Firebase since quite recently, so any help and/or advice is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I could solve it!** And if you have the same problem, here's how.
I went the way round and used a `transaction` instead of `FieldValue.update()`.
Transactions work a bit differently, so I do recommend reading the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#dart) first.

Basically, I did the following:

```
void update() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      final snapshot = await transaction.get(docRef);
      final amount = snapshot.get("example");
      if (amount > 0) {
        final newAmount = snapshot.get("example") - 1;
        transaction.update(docRef, {"example": newAmount});
      }
    });
  }
```

This way, I stored in `amount` the current `example` field value, and if it was greater than 0 then it would update itself subtracting 1, therefore avoiding it to ever reach less than 0.

Although I used a different method, I want to thank Frank van Puffelen and Jiří Petera for their help to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of (or maybe in addition to) doing this in your code, I recommend doing it in Firebase's security rules. Since these rules are enforced on the server, there is no way for even a malicious client to circumvent then.

To [validate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) that the `example` field never becomes negative, you can do:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
      allow write: if request.resource.data.example > 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would this prevent the entire document from being updated, or just the field? I want to set a validation to prevent a document’s field from going below 0 during an update, but the other fields should be allowed to get updated. Not sure if the best way to handle this is in the security rules, or via an Interface or Class in the Cloud Functions.

Comment: The entire document. There's no way to reject just the one field from security rules, you'll have to use a transaction (+ rules) for that.

Comment: Thank you! I do have logic set in a transaction, but it feels like that logic should sit closer to the database than an update function/trigger. I’ll keep playing with getting an interface or class in a model to take care of that, so that subsequent functions won’t have to. It’s a quest!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the doc reference first, check the value and only increment if it complies with the if.

I do not come from Dart language background so feel free do correct the syntax. But hopefully you will get an idea.

Ex:

```
final userRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid)
userRef.get().then(res=>{
  if(res.example > 45){
    userRef.update({
      "example": FieldValue.increment(-45),
    })
  }
})
```